# Right way to change a value on a map on clojure

Tags: clojure

Alright, I'm new to clojure, this should be easy but for the life of me I can't find the answer

Let's say I have this map

```
(def mymap {:a 10 :b 15})
```

Now I want to change the value of :a to 5. I don't know how to do this properly

I know `update` and `assoc` can make changes but they both receive a function as last argument, which applies to the value. I don't want that, I don't want any function to run, I just want to simply set :a to 5.

I think I can pass an anonymous function that simply returns 5 and ignores the arg, but is this the right way? Doesn't look good to me

`(update mymap :a (fn [arg] 5))`

Comment: `assoc` is what you're looking for; no last-arg function. https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc

Comment: `assoc` does not take a function - `(assoc mymap :a 5)`.

Comment: `assoc-in` is the way for a nested map: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc-in

Answer (score 11):

[`assoc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc) does not take a function as its last argument; unless you were wanting to associate a function with a key in the map. `(assoc mymap :a 5)` does what you want.

I'll add though, `update`, which *does* take a function, could be used here as well when combined with `constantly` or just another function (although there's no reason to use them over `assoc`):

```
; constantly returns a function that throws away any arguments given to it,
; and "constantly" returns the given value
(update mymap :a (constantly 5))

; Basically the same as above
(update mymap :a (fn [_] 5))
```

Answer (score 3):

Do keep in mind that as mymap is immutable, so calling `(update mymap :a (constantly 5))` or `(assoc mymap :a 5)` will return a map `{:a 5 :b 15}`, further references to mymap will continue to return the original value of `{:a 10 :b 15}`.

If you want to update the value for later calls, you can look at using atoms.

```
(defonce mymap (atom {:a 10 :b 15}))

(defn change-mymap [value]
  (swap! mymap #(assoc % :a value)))
```

Just make sure that when you want to reference the value of an atom, you dereference it with the @ symbol. For example: `(clojure.pprint/pprint @mymap)`

When you call `(change-mymap 5)` this will update the stored mymap value to set `:a` to a new value, leaving any other key-value pairs in your map alone.  This can be helpful when you are mapping in updated state in client/server code when responding to inputs from the other system.

Also note that for nested maps, such as

```
(defonce nested (atom {:a "a value"
                       :b {:inner "Another value"
                           :count 3
                           :another {:value 5}}}))
```

You can address a particular value in your map by a path vector. You can use the `get-in` function to retrieve the value `(get-in @nested [:b :another :value])`
and you can use `assoc-in` or `update-in` with a path to update the values. This also allows you to extend a map. For example, with the above value of nested, you can add a whole section to the tree:
`(swap! nested #(assoc-in % [:a :b :c :d] "foo"))`
will update the initial map to look like this:

```
{:a {:b {:c {:d "foo"}}}
 :b {:inner "Another value"
     :count 3
     :another {:value 5}}}
```